# Why does my git log output show both origin and origin/master, origin/HEAD when using a remote. These entries seem redundant to me

Tags: git, git-branch

I am going through git branching concepts from [3.1 Git Branching - Branches in a Nutshell](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

I am playing with dummy repository.

`git log --oneline --decorate` gives following output.

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate
d0006a6 (HEAD, origin, tag: Test1, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Minor change 
1437545 Minor change
69a948a Added Makefile
617ffeb Spell correction
6bf9b3f First commit
$ git branch 
* master
$ git remote --v
origin  /home/adil/work/git/repo/ (fetch)
origin  /home/adil/work/git/repo/ (push)
```

I am not clear with multiple entries with origin and master. Like origin, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master

The sample output in the URL gives:

```
f30ab (HEAD, master, testing) add feature #32 - ability to add new
```

Similarly I was expecting the output to be:

```
d0006a6 (HEAD, tag: Test1, master) Minor change
```

One thing could be difference point is, in our case, its having remote. So I think that's why origin is coming but why origin, origin/master, origin/HEAD 3 extra entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something fundamental you have to understand about git.

- `origin` is your remote. It can be named anything else, but the main remote is named origin by convention
- `origin/master` is your main or master branch in the remote named `origin`. Again the name master is simply convention and it can be anything else.
- `origin/HEAD` is wherever your git is pointing to currently. If you have multiple branches like master and develop, you can checkout to develop. Effectively that action will point HEAD to develop. It is possible to use HEAD like any other branch in git commands. It is just a pointer to what branch you are on currently.

**EDIT**

Maybe I misunderstood the question, so some more explanation

The three of them are shown so that you know the status of the three things I have explained above.

- `origin/HEAD` at a commit tells you the *default branch of origin* is pointing to that commit
- `master` tells you that your local repo is at that particular commit
- `origin/master` tells you that these changes have been pushed to remote and the `master` branch in your remote is up to date with your local repo

If you had not pushed your changes to remote repo, the `origin/HEAD` and `origin/master` would be at the commit that was last pushed to the remote

Comment: He was asking why does it show both `origin` and `origin/master`, `origin/HEAD`. Since this seems to be redundant.

Comment: Thanks [TheGeorgeous](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1782570/thegeorgeous) for explanation. I understand. So by going this, it looks like to me "origin" is redundant as origin/master and origin/HEAD actually gives the information. Or in other words, will origin be ever different from origin/HEAD?

Comment: @Adil, I doubt if the `origin` there is meant to be `origin/HEAD`. It is more likely to mean `origin` the remote to differentiate from any other remotes you may have. Frankly I haven't seen origin in any of my repos.